# Hang whilst scraping page using requests in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to extract a webpage off of the internet, but on some pages (e.g. Tesco's website) I get warning and then it just hangs.

Warning is

> InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to
> host 'www.tesco.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly
> advised. See:
> https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

I am using requests to make the connection and get the page.

Minimum working code:

```
import requests

def extract_page(url):
    page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    print(f'status code : {page.status_code}')

    if page.status_code != 200:
        print(f"URL '{url} returned status code {page.status_code}")
        return

extract_page('https://www.tesco.com/')
```

Any guidance on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated, especially as some sites such as Wikipedia work just fine and I couldn't see any other pages that addresses it.

Comment: [Removing `verify=False` should remove the `InsecureRequestWarning`.](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.linkchecker/issues/57#issuecomment-499473514) I hope this helps.

Comment: @user70 It removes the warning, but doesn't stop the hang :(

Comment: I wonder if they have some bot detection in there. Try changing the User-Agent header to that of a real browser. I have had to do this in the past.

Comment: [fake-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/)